How to use i18n files to localize Highcharts weekday labels?
I am working on a project where I need to localize the weekday labels in Highcharts. I know that I can do it by calling Highcharts.setOptions() before creating the chart, like this:
javascript
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
weekdays: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi']
}
});
However, I want to use i18n translation files instead of hardcoding the labels. My current application already uses i18n for other parts of the UI. How can I pass the weekday labels from i18n files to Highcharts?
enter image description here
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
weekdays: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi']
}
});
Have added levels but unsure how to translate labels.

We can Create a Key value pair before and After Binding Data . Other than that is there any approach.

Suppose you are using default i18n of Angular, you can prepare these values with $localize Monday`` before use in the label list. That how I worked with Chartjs, I think Highchart can apply the same concept

Can you please share your ChartJS Implementation

In ChartJs, I can prepare a list of labels, I just get these labels from a list of predefined value with $localize, the chart will be init when component finish rendering, to be sure that the translation are there

You need to use Highcharts.setOptions before creating a chart and force re-render after using it again. The below example uses @ngx-translate package, but you can implement a similar approach with the native i18n Angular mechanism and the $localize function.
Component .ts:
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  lang = '';

  changeLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.translate.get('months').subscribe((translated: string[]) => {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
          months: translated
        }
      });
      this.lang = lang;
    });
  }

  ...
}

Component .html:
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  *ngIf="lang === 'pl'"
></highcharts-chart>
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  *ngIf="lang === 'en'"
></highcharts-chart>
<button (click)="changeLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button (click)="changeLanguage('pl')">Polski</button>


Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ohmbue
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang
